# Function annotation for return of compact() function

Tags: phpstorm

How to write function annotation for return of compact() result?

```
public function getParams()
{
    $var1 = 1;
    $var2 = 2;
    return compact('var1', 'var2');
}
```

When I use function `getParams()` I get variables, but phpStorm dont know them with warning message "Undefined variable ...".
How to write `getParams()` return annotation which this code:

```
extract(getParams());
```

will understand what variables returned/extracted?

I know that I can use annotation for extract() like this:

```
/**
* @var string $var1
* @var string $var2
*/
```

but it must be under all extract() functions and I dont want it.

Comment: I doubt PHPStorm can magically analyze which variables you're extracting. In your case, it's quite clear, but it could also be from a dynamically generated and/or complex associative array. So you can either 1) do what your did, 2) use `isset` or 3) suppress the inspection (or even disable it, but I wouldn't recommend it). Unrelated, but your `compact` syntax is wrong, should be `compact('var1', 'var2')`.

Comment: A feature request for extract() support: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-2416

Comment: I believe there's no standard or widespread annotation format for associative arrays. I've seen custom formats invented by frameworks but probably nothing you can use from an IDE. PhpStorm can be fed with data files in a custom format to help code intelligence but I've never used it—I can't even remember how the feature is called.